# What's wrong with this postgres trigger function?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, stored-functions

I am new in postgres, created this trigger function to summarize a larger table to another table, I'm using pgAdmin when I run this in query tools, nothing will happen it don't give me an error or give me any successful message, what's wrong with it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_sum_usage() RETURNS trigger AS $insert_sum_usage$
DECLARE t timestamptz;
DECLARE u double precision;
BEGIN
t=(SELECT time FROM public.temp_time  where id=1 ); 
IF ( t  >  now() - interval '600 seconds')
THEN RETURN NEW;
ELSE
    u=(SELECT SUM(value)  FROM public.temp_usage WHERE labels[12] = 46  AND (labels[3] = 32 OR labels[3] = 62));
    INSERT INTO public.temp_sum_usage VALUES (NEW.time, u);
    UPDATE public.temp_time SET  time=NEW.time WHERE id=1;
RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END; 
$insert_sum_usage$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_sum_usage AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.temp_usage FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_sum_usage();
```

Comment: Stop and just *don't*. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing sum over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the sum, you can always query it and get the *right* result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: I see no problem with your trigger definition, other the conceptual one in the comment above. Bot I cannot follow the logic. Please describe your intention in more detail and describe how exactly your code misbehaves.

Comment: I found the problem, this trigger takes lots of time to perform and inserting rate in main table is huge and it makes a huge queue and it made problem in the process, I should use cron to do so, @sticky bit you are right, my method was the worst choice

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say, why this trigger do nothing. There are lot of constraints, and probably one constraint can be false. For this situation, the `RAISE NOTICE` statement is your best friend. You can see values of some variables or points where the process leaved the trigger:

```
IF ( t  >  now() - interval '600 seconds')
  RAISE NOTICE 'fast leaving (%, %)', t, now();
  THEN RETURN NEW;
ELSE
  ...
```

Just note: PLpgSQL is not C based language, so parenthesis around `IF` expressions are useless.

Comment: I found the problem, this trigger takes lots of time to perform and inserting rate in main table is huge and it makes a huge queue and it made problem in the process, I should use cron to do so, thanks for replay ;-)